# For every api call my bobcatserver and all other beans are recreated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

```
org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver: Could not find key 'spring.profiles.default' in any property source
28 Aug 2020 23:01:40,696 [DEBUG] f5dec873-4e7d-4a65-939a-258fb82b0cdb (Coral Endpoint : 12) org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning

28 Aug 2020 23:01:40,696 [INFO] f5dec873-4e7d-4a65-939a-258fb82b0cdb (Coral Endpoint : 12) org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'com.amazon.nawsbeejakservice.activity.GetMetadataActivity' with a different definition: replacing 

[Root bean: class [com.amazon.nawsbeejakservice.activity.GetMetadataActivity]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with 
[Root bean: class [com.amazon.nawsbeejakservice.activity.GetMetadataActivity]; scope=prototype; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
```

for every api call my bobcatserver and all other beans are recreated. when i check logs i see when the service gets up its creating beans with scope=; and when i call some api all the beans are re-created with scope=prototype;

How do i avoid same bean creation multiple times. (currently its changing all the objects for every request)

Comment: What AWS resources are you using for your service?

Comment: i am using Amazon Elastic container service

Answer (score 0):

Basically not sure why but my spring container is initializing for every requests which created multiple containers each one with one bobcatserver and all other beans. bobcatserver from all the containers were trying to access the port. only the first bovcat has got connected and rest are throwing address already in use. i got over this by upgrading from 4.3 to 5.1  spring version. it worked